# Error Cooja software Simulation

Tags: contiki

After enabling `tunslip6` package in `contiki`, I got an error when I gave this command.

> sudo ./tunslip6 -a 127.0.0.1 aaaa::1/64

Error is like

> sudo:./tunslip6 command not found

Please give me a solution to get rid of this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you don't have executable in `/contiki/tools`.

Perform the following steps:

In terminal, change your working directory to `/contiki/tools` and then compile:

```
cc tunslip6.c -o tunslip6
```

If you `./tunslip6` you will see something as follows:

```
tunslip6: usage: ./tunslip6 [-B baudrate] [-H] [-L] [-s siodev] [-t tundev] [-T] [-v verbosity] [-d delay] [-a serveraddress] [-p serverport] ipaddress: Success
```

Now your command shall work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You may try to cd to the directory /home/user/contiki/tools and do the command.